# Dictionary with Keys inside Keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to find a way to return the 1st value inside the key 'hw' for keys 1 and 2 and sum them but I cannot think of a way.It needs to work for any number of keys, not just 1 and 2 but even if there were 10 or so. The 1 and 2 are the students, the 'hw','qz',,etc are the categories of assignments,every student will have hw,qz,ex,pr and there will be 3 qz,3hw,3pr,3ex for each student. I need to return all the students 1st, hw grade, 1st quiz grade, 2nd hw grade..etc

```python
grades = {
        1: {
            'pr': [18, 15],
            'hw': [16, 27, 25], 
            'qz': [8, 10, 5],
            'ex': [83, 93],
            },
        2: {
            'pr': [20, 18],
            'hw': [17, 23, 28],
            'qz': [9, 9, 8],
            'ex': [84, 98],
            },
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried `Grades[1]['hw'][0] + Grades[2]['hw'][0]` yet?

Comment: yes that works but it needs to work for any number of keys, not just 1 and 2 but even if there were 10 or so

Comment: The same general technique will work for any number of keys. Can you give more details on your requirements and an example where you've attempted to implement.

Comment: If I understand correctly, something like `sum(Grades[key]['hw'][0] for key in Grades.keys())`?

Answer (score 2):

More succinctly (and Pythonicly):

```
hw_sum = sum([grades[key]['hw'][0] for key in grades])
```

Comment: technically, you don't even need to create a list

Comment: Rafael, the code above is very easy to read for any decent Python developer. List comprehensions are a very often used feature of the language. And it happens to be a one-liner, which is nice.

Answer (score 0):

> return the 1st value inside the key 'hw' for keys 1 and 2 and sum them

It helps to use explanatory names so we know what the moving parts are meant to be. I've chosen descriptive names somewhat arbitrarily by guessing at the meaning.

## Succinct solution

```python
grades_by_year_and_subject = {
        1: {
            'pr': [18, 15],
            'hw': [16, 27, 25], 
            'qz': [8, 10, 5],
            'ex': [83, 93],
            },
        2: {
            'pr': [20, 18],
            'hw': [17, 23, 28],
            'qz': [9, 9, 8],
            'ex': [84, 98],
            },
        }

sum_of_grades_for_year_1_and_2_for_subject_hw = sum(
        grades[0] for grades in (
            grades_by_subject['hw']
            for (year, grades_by_subject) in
                grades_by_year_and_subject.items()
            if year in [1, 2]
            )
        )
```

Breaking this into several smaller problems:

## Sum a collection of values

```python
sum_of_grades = sum(values)
```

## Get the set of first values from a collection of lists

```python
set_of_first_grades = {
        values[0] for values in collection}
```

## Make a generator of the values for key `'hw'` in each dict from a collection

```python
generator_of_hw_value_lists = (
        values_dict['hw'] for values_dict in
        collection_of_dicts.values())
```

## Reduce a dictionary only to those items with keys `1` or `2`

```python
mapping_of_values_for_key_1_and_2 = {
        key: value
        for (key, value) in values_dict.items()
        if key in [1, 2]}
```

## Verbose solution

```python
grades_by_year_and_subject = {
        1: {
            'pr': [18, 15],
            'hw': [16, 27, 25], 
            'qz': [8, 10, 5],
            'ex': [83, 93],
            },
        2: {
            'pr': [20, 18],
            'hw': [17, 23, 28],
            'qz': [9, 9, 8],
            'ex': [84, 98],
            },
        }

grades_for_year_1_and_2_by_subject = {
        year: grades_by_subject
        for (year, grades_by_subject) in
            grades_by_year_and_subject.items()
        if year in [1, 2]}

grades_for_year_1_and_2_for_subject_hw = (
        grades_by_subject['hw']
        for grades_by_subject in
            grades_for_year_1_and_2_by_subject.values())

sum_of_grades_for_year_1_and_2_for_subject_hw = sum(
        grades[0] for grades in grades_for_year_1_and_2_for_subject_hw)
```